# android: getResources().getIdentifier NotFound Exception

Tags: android, getresource, getstring

I get my Data via json. Put it in a Hashmap und list it in a ListView.
That works fine!

Now I want something like this:

```
String myArt=report_TJ_+e.getString("artID");
```

That does not work in my combination. Here is my Code:

```
  try{
    //String text = getString(R.string.report_TJ);
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("uTraf");
    mylist.clear();
    String report_TJ_btn = null;
            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                String imageString=report_TJ_btn+e.getString("artID");
                String myArt = getString(getResources().getIdentifier(imageString, "", getPackageName()));

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("first", myArt + "Stau: " + e.getString("road") + ", " + e.getString("county"));
                map.put("second", e.getString("timestamp") + ", " + e.getString("suburb"));
                mylist.add(map);
            }       
  }
```

Error:
E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set `"string"` and not `"strings"` as the second parameter.

```
String myArt = getString(getResources().getIdentifier(imageString, "string", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you need this:

`String myArt = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("report_TJ_btn " + e.getString("artID"), "strings", getPackageName()));`

Comment: sorry, again the same error.
eclipse want that I do this
String report_TJ_btn = null;

is this correct?

Comment: OK I have a: getString(R.string.report_TJ_btn1) and in the strings.xml different languages. the artID gives a Number: report_TJ_btn + artID = report_TJ_btn1 = getString(R.string.report_TJ_btn1) That is what I want

Answer (score 1):

Use String report_TJ_btn = "";